# Почему не работает justify-self?

Tags: css, flexbox

Как последнюю строку с  классом .bottom переместить вниз контейнера?
Выставляю

> justify-self: flex-end;

Но ничего не происходит. Строка по прежнему прижата к верху(flex-start).

https://jsfiddle.net/manking99/2qwc9f6L/12/

```
<div class="block">

<div class="row row1">строка 1</div>
<div class="row row2">строка 2</div>
<div class="row row3 bottom">Итог</div>

</div>


.block{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 40vw;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.row{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}

.row .bottom{
    justify-self: flex-end;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-self

> In flexbox layouts, this property is *ignored*.
>
> В контексте flexbox-а это свойство *игнорируется*.

Сделайте последнему блоку `margin-top: auto`.

```css
.block{
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 40vw;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.row{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}

.row.bottom {
    margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

<div class="row row1">строка 1</div>
<div class="row row2">строка 2</div>
<div class="row row3 bottom">Итог</div>

</div>
```

P.S. А ещё у вас лишний пробел в CSS. Правильно `.row.bottom`, а не `.row .bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 40vw;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.row {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}

.bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">

  <div class="row row1">строка 1</div>
  <div class="row row2">строка 2</div>
  <div class="row row3 bottom">Итог</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Плохо. Если строк много, то итог повиснет в непонятном месте

Comment: @AlexeyTen, проверьте то, что Вы написали.

Comment: Добавьте ещё штук 30 `<div class="row row2">строка 2</div>` и посмотрите.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, дак причем тут это? Вы взгляните на строку `.block { height: 40vw; }`, тут просто банальное ограничение по высоте. Ясно, что полетит все, т.к. она (высота) ограничена)

Comment: И что? Если блоков будет больше, то у автора они просто вылезут за пределы контрейнера, но при этом «итого» всё равно будет последним. В вашем примере «итого» будет висеть поперёк других строчек, т.к. вынесено из потока.